# Cannot check tables, views in update wizard when updating model from database at Visual Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have a Microsoft SQL Server database connected to an Entity Framework Web API project. I run SSMS & VS 2017.

I erased some column in the model and I want to re-create it with updating from the database. When I try updating model from DB option on the edmx file, there is an update wizard.

The update wizard doesn't allow me to check and table or view in the wizard. It also doesn't add the column from the database to model.

I also have errors as follows (that maybe will disappear when the column will be added to the model):

> Error 3023: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 309:Column GamesScores.GameDateCreation in table GamesScores must be mapped: It has no default value and is not nullable.
>   01-Data Access Layer  C:\projects\webApi\memory match game\Memory Match Game\01-Data Access Layer\MemoryMatch.edmx    310
>
> Error CS0006  Metadata file 'C:\projects\webApi\memory match game\Memory Match Game\03-Business Logic Layer\bin\Debug\03-Business Logic Layer.dll' could not be found 
>   04- Web Api   C:\projects\webApi\memory match game\Memory Match Game\04- Web
>   Api\CSC   1   Active

[Here is the mapping of the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk1eQ.png)

And here is the EDMX code in a HTML view:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
  <!-- EF Runtime content -->
  <edmx:Runtime>
    <!-- SSDL content -->
    <edmx:StorageModels>
    <Schema Namespace="MemoryMatchModel.Store" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2012" Alias="Self" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns:customannotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">
        <EntityType Name="ContactMessages">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="MessageID" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="MessageID" Type="int" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="MessageTimeStamp" Type="datetime" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Phone" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="50" />
          <Property Name="Email" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="50" />
          <Property Name="MessageText" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="200" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="Feedbacks">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="FeedbackID" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="FeedbackID" Type="int" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="UserID" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="FeedbackTimeStamp" Type="datetime" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="FeedbackText" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="250" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="GamesScores">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="GameScoreID" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="GameScoreID" Type="int" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="UserID" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="GameDateCreation" Type="datetime" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="GameDuration" Type="time" Precision="7" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="GameSteps" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="Images">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="ImageID" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="ImageID" Type="int" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="ImageName" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="256" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="sysdiagrams">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="diagram_id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="name" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="128" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="principal_id" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="diagram_id" Type="int" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="version" Type="int" />
          <Property Name="definition" Type="varbinary(max)" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="Users">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="UserID" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="UserID" Type="int" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="FullName" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="50" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="UserName" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="50" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Password" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="50" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Email" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="50" />
          <Property Name="Birthdate" Type="date" />
        </EntityType>
        <Association Name="FK_Feedbacks_Users">
          <End Role="Users" Type="Self.Users" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="Feedbacks" Type="Self.Feedbacks" Multiplicity="*" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="Users">
              <PropertyRef Name="UserID" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="Feedbacks">
              <PropertyRef Name="UserID" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Association Name="FK_GamesScores_Users">
          <End Role="Users" Type="Self.Users" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="GamesScores" Type="Self.GamesScores" Multiplicity="*" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="Users">
              <PropertyRef Name="UserID" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="GamesScores">
              <PropertyRef Name="UserID" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Function Name="fn_diagramobjects" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo" ReturnType="int" />
        <Function Name="sp_alterdiagram" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
          <Parameter Name="diagramname" Type="nvarchar" Mode="In" />
          <Parameter Name="owner_id" Type="int" Mode="In" />
          <Parameter Name="version" Type="int" Mode="In" />
          <Parameter Name="definition" Type="varbinary(max)" Mode="In" />
        </Function>
        <Function Name="sp_creatediagram" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
          <Parameter Name="diagramname" Type="nvarchar" Mode="In" />
          <Parameter Name="owner_id" Type="int" Mode="In" />
          <Parameter Name="version" Type="int" Mode="In" />
          <Parameter Name="definition" Type="varbinary(max)" Mode="In" />
        </Function>
        <Function Name="sp_dropdiagram" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
          <Parameter Name="diagramname" Type="nvarchar" Mode="In" />
          <Parameter Name="owner_id" Type="int" Mode="In" />
        </Function>
        <Function Name="sp_helpdiagramdefinition" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
          <Parameter Name="diagramname" Type="nvarchar" Mode="In" />
          <Parameter Name="owner_id" Type="int" Mode="In" />
        </Function>
        <Function Name="sp_helpdiagrams" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
          <Parameter Name="diagramname" Type="nvarchar" Mode="In" />
          <Parameter Name="owner_id" Type="int" Mode="In" />
        </Function>
        <Function Name="sp_renamediagram" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
          <Parameter Name="diagramname" Type="nvarchar" Mode="In" />
          <Parameter Name="owner_id" Type="int" Mode="In" />
          <Parameter Name="new_diagramname" Type="nvarchar" Mode="In" />
        </Function>
        <Function Name="sp_upgraddiagrams" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo" />
        <EntityContainer Name="MemoryMatchModelStoreContainer">
          <EntitySet Name="ContactMessages" EntityType="Self.ContactMessages" Schema="dbo" store:Type="Tables" />
          <EntitySet Name="Feedbacks" EntityType="Self.Feedbacks" Schema="dbo" store:Type="Tables" />
          <EntitySet Name="GamesScores" EntityType="Self.GamesScores" Schema="dbo" store:Type="Tables" />
          <EntitySet Name="Images" EntityType="Self.Images" Schema="dbo" store:Type="Tables" />
          <EntitySet Name="sysdiagrams" EntityType="Self.sysdiagrams" Schema="dbo" store:Type="Tables" />
          <EntitySet Name="Users" EntityType="Self.Users" Schema="dbo" store:Type="Tables" />
          <AssociationSet Name="FK_Feedbacks_Users" Association="Self.FK_Feedbacks_Users">
            <End Role="Users" EntitySet="Users" />
            <End Role="Feedbacks" EntitySet="Feedbacks" />
          </AssociationSet>
          <AssociationSet Name="FK_GamesScores_Users" Association="Self.FK_GamesScores_Users">
            <End Role="Users" EntitySet="Users" />
            <End Role="GamesScores" EntitySet="GamesScores" />
          </AssociationSet>
        </EntityContainer>
      </Schema></edmx:StorageModels>
    <!-- CSDL content -->
    <edmx:ConceptualModels>
      <Schema Namespace="MemoryMatchModel" Alias="Self" annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns:customannotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
        <EntityType Name="ContactMessage">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="MessageID" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="MessageID" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="MessageTimeStamp" Type="DateTime" Nullable="false" Precision="3" />
          <Property Name="Phone" Type="String" MaxLength="50" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
          <Property Name="Email" Type="String" MaxLength="50" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
          <Property Name="MessageText" Type="String" MaxLength="200" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="Feedback">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="FeedbackID" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="FeedbackID" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="UserID" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="FeedbackTimeStamp" Type="DateTime" Nullable="false" Precision="3" />
          <Property Name="FeedbackText" Type="String" MaxLength="250" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" Nullable="false" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="User" Relationship="Self.FK_Feedbacks_Users" FromRole="Feedbacks" ToRole="Users" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="GamesScore">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="GameScoreID" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="GameScoreID" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="UserID" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="GameSteps" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="User" Relationship="Self.FK_GamesScores_Users" FromRole="GamesScores" ToRole="Users" />
          <Property Name="GameDuration" Type="Time" Nullable="false" Precision="7" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="Image">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="ImageID" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="ImageID" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="ImageName" Type="String" MaxLength="256" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="sysdiagram">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="diagram_id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="name" Type="String" MaxLength="128" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="principal_id" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="diagram_id" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="version" Type="Int32" />
          <Property Name="definition" Type="Binary" MaxLength="Max" FixedLength="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="User">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="UserID" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="UserID" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="FullName" Type="String" MaxLength="50" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="UserName" Type="String" MaxLength="50" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Password" Type="String" MaxLength="50" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Email" Type="String" MaxLength="50" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
          <Property Name="Birthdate" Type="DateTime" Precision="0" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="Feedbacks" Relationship="Self.FK_Feedbacks_Users" FromRole="Users" ToRole="Feedbacks" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="GamesScores" Relationship="Self.FK_GamesScores_Users" FromRole="Users" ToRole="GamesScores" />
        </EntityType>
        <Association Name="FK_Feedbacks_Users">
          <End Role="Users" Type="Self.User" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="Feedbacks" Type="Self.Feedback" Multiplicity="*" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="Users">
              <PropertyRef Name="UserID" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="Feedbacks">
              <PropertyRef Name="UserID" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Association Name="FK_GamesScores_Users">
          <End Role="Users" Type="Self.User" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="GamesScores" Type="Self.GamesScore" Multiplicity="*" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="Users">
              <PropertyRef Name="UserID" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="GamesScores">
              <PropertyRef Name="UserID" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <EntityContainer Name="MemoryMatchEntities" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
          <EntitySet Name="ContactMessages" EntityType="Self.ContactMessage" />
          <EntitySet Name="Feedbacks" EntityType="Self.Feedback" />
          <EntitySet Name="GamesScores" EntityType="Self.GamesScore" />
          <EntitySet Name="Images" EntityType="Self.Image" />
          <EntitySet Name="sysdiagrams" EntityType="Self.sysdiagram" />
          <EntitySet Name="Users" EntityType="Self.User" />
          <AssociationSet Name="FK_Feedbacks_Users" Association="Self.FK_Feedbacks_Users">
            <End Role="Users" EntitySet="Users" />
            <End Role="Feedbacks" EntitySet="Feedbacks" />
          </AssociationSet>
          <AssociationSet Name="FK_GamesScores_Users" Association="Self.FK_GamesScores_Users">
            <End Role="Users" EntitySet="Users" />
            <End Role="GamesScores" EntitySet="GamesScores" />
          </AssociationSet>
          <FunctionImport Name="sp_alterdiagram">
            <Parameter Name="diagramname" Mode="In" Type="String" />
            <Parameter Name="owner_id" Mode="In" Type="Int32" />
            <Parameter Name="version" Mode="In" Type="Int32" />
            <Parameter Name="definition" Mode="In" Type="Binary" />
          </FunctionImport>
          <FunctionImport Name="sp_creatediagram">
            <Parameter Name="diagramname" Mode="In" Type="String" />
            <Parameter Name="owner_id" Mode="In" Type="Int32" />
            <Parameter Name="version" Mode="In" Type="Int32" />
            <Parameter Name="definition" Mode="In" Type="Binary" />
          </FunctionImport>
          <FunctionImport Name="sp_dropdiagram">
            <Parameter Name="diagramname" Mode="In" Type="String" />
            <Parameter Name="owner_id" Mode="In" Type="Int32" />
          </FunctionImport>
          <FunctionImport Name="sp_helpdiagramdefinition" ReturnType="Collection(MemoryMatchModel.sp_helpdiagramdefinition_Result)">
            <Parameter Name="diagramname" Mode="In" Type="String" />
            <Parameter Name="owner_id" Mode="In" Type="Int32" />
          </FunctionImport>
          <FunctionImport Name="sp_helpdiagrams" ReturnType="Collection(MemoryMatchModel.sp_helpdiagrams_Result)">
            <Parameter Name="diagramname" Mode="In" Type="String" />
            <Parameter Name="owner_id" Mode="In" Type="Int32" />
          </FunctionImport>
          <FunctionImport Name="sp_renamediagram">
            <Parameter Name="diagramname" Mode="In" Type="String" />
            <Parameter Name="owner_id" Mode="In" Type="Int32" />
            <Parameter Name="new_diagramname" Mode="In" Type="String" />
          </FunctionImport>
          <FunctionImport Name="sp_upgraddiagrams" />
        </EntityContainer>
        <ComplexType Name="sp_helpdiagramdefinition_Result">
          <Property Type="Int32" Name="version" Nullable="true" />
          <Property Type="Binary" Name="definition" Nullable="true" />
        </ComplexType>
        <ComplexType Name="sp_helpdiagrams_Result">
          <Property Type="String" Name="Database" Nullable="true" MaxLength="128" />
          <Property Type="String" Name="Name" Nullable="false" MaxLength="128" />
          <Property Type="Int32" Name="ID" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Type="String" Name="Owner" Nullable="true" MaxLength="128" />
          <Property Type="Int32" Name="OwnerID" Nullable="false" />
        </ComplexType>
      </Schema>
    </edmx:ConceptualModels>
    <!-- C-S mapping content -->
    <edmx:Mappings>
      <Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs">
        <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="MemoryMatchModelStoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="MemoryMatchEntities">
          <EntitySetMapping Name="ContactMessages">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="MemoryMatchModel.ContactMessage">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="ContactMessages">
                <ScalarProperty Name="MessageID" ColumnName="MessageID" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="MessageTimeStamp" ColumnName="MessageTimeStamp" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Phone" ColumnName="Phone" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Email" ColumnName="Email" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="MessageText" ColumnName="MessageText" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
          <EntitySetMapping Name="Feedbacks">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="MemoryMatchModel.Feedback">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Feedbacks">
                <ScalarProperty Name="FeedbackID" ColumnName="FeedbackID" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="UserID" ColumnName="UserID" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="FeedbackTimeStamp" ColumnName="FeedbackTimeStamp" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="FeedbackText" ColumnName="FeedbackText" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
          <EntitySetMapping Name="GamesScores">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="MemoryMatchModel.GamesScore">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="GamesScores">
                <ScalarProperty Name="GameDuration" ColumnName="GameDuration" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="GameScoreID" ColumnName="GameScoreID" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="UserID" ColumnName="UserID" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="GameSteps" ColumnName="GameSteps" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
          <EntitySetMapping Name="Images">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="MemoryMatchModel.Image">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Images">
                <ScalarProperty Name="ImageID" ColumnName="ImageID" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="ImageName" ColumnName="ImageName" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
          <EntitySetMapping Name="sysdiagrams">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="MemoryMatchModel.sysdiagram">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="sysdiagrams">
                <ScalarProperty Name="name" ColumnName="name" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="principal_id" ColumnName="principal_id" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="diagram_id" ColumnName="diagram_id" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="version" ColumnName="version" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="definition" ColumnName="definition" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
          <EntitySetMapping Name="Users">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="MemoryMatchModel.User">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Users">
                <ScalarProperty Name="UserID" ColumnName="UserID" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="FullName" ColumnName="FullName" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="UserName" ColumnName="UserName" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Password" ColumnName="Password" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Email" ColumnName="Email" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Birthdate" ColumnName="Birthdate" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
          <FunctionImportMapping FunctionImportName="sp_alterdiagram" FunctionName="MemoryMatchModel.Store.sp_alterdiagram" />
          <FunctionImportMapping FunctionImportName="sp_creatediagram" FunctionName="MemoryMatchModel.Store.sp_creatediagram" />
          <FunctionImportMapping FunctionImportName="sp_dropdiagram" FunctionName="MemoryMatchModel.Store.sp_dropdiagram" />
          <FunctionImportMapping FunctionImportName="sp_helpdiagramdefinition" FunctionName="MemoryMatchModel.Store.sp_helpdiagramdefinition">
            <ResultMapping>
              <ComplexTypeMapping TypeName="MemoryMatchModel.sp_helpdiagramdefinition_Result">
                <ScalarProperty Name="version" ColumnName="version" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="definition" ColumnName="definition" />
              </ComplexTypeMapping>
            </ResultMapping>
          </FunctionImportMapping>
          <FunctionImportMapping FunctionImportName="sp_helpdiagrams" FunctionName="MemoryMatchModel.Store.sp_helpdiagrams">
            <ResultMapping>
              <ComplexTypeMapping TypeName="MemoryMatchModel.sp_helpdiagrams_Result">
                <ScalarProperty Name="Database" ColumnName="Database" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Name" ColumnName="Name" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="ID" ColumnName="ID" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Owner" ColumnName="Owner" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="OwnerID" ColumnName="OwnerID" />
              </ComplexTypeMapping>
            </ResultMapping>
          </FunctionImportMapping>
          <FunctionImportMapping FunctionImportName="sp_renamediagram" FunctionName="MemoryMatchModel.Store.sp_renamediagram" />
          <FunctionImportMapping FunctionImportName="sp_upgraddiagrams" FunctionName="MemoryMatchModel.Store.sp_upgraddiagrams" />
        </EntityContainerMapping>
      </Mapping>
    </edmx:Mappings>
  </edmx:Runtime>
  <!-- EF Designer content (DO NOT EDIT MANUALLY BELOW HERE) -->
  <Designer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
    <Connection>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="MetadataArtifactProcessing" Value="EmbedInOutputAssembly" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </Connection>
    <Options>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="ValidateOnBuild" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="EnablePluralization" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="IncludeForeignKeysInModel" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="UseLegacyProvider" Value="false" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="CodeGenerationStrategy" Value="None" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </Options>
    <!-- Diagram content (shape and connector positions) -->
    <Diagrams></Diagrams>
  </Designer>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Why can't I add the column `GameDateCreation` to my model from the database?

Is it because of the errors I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned column `GameDateCreation` under `<EntityType Name="GamesScores">` in section `SSDL`. But, You have not mentioned same column `GameDateCreation` mentioned under `<EntitySetMapping Name="GamesScores">` in `Mappings` section.

There should be below mentioned line code under `<EntitySetMapping Name="GamesScores">`.

```
<ScalarProperty Name="GameDateCreation" ColumnName="GameDateCreation" />
```

Other workaround will be remove all references of column `GameDateCreation` from `edmx` file and try to add column to model from database.

Please let me know how you go.

Comment: First of all Thank you very much for helping me out. I am new in this. I tried editing the edmx file using the html editor option in VS. This was not a good choice since you cannot make "undo" if you accidently erase something. it also autosave the file. By the way how is the best way to edit the edmx file? Because I erased the file I copied it again from this thread...

Comment: Now For your answer: I saw there is <EntitySetMapping Name="GamesScores"> in Mappings section. Please look again I think I did saw it.

Comment: Best way to edit `edmx` file is Open it with **XML (Text) Editor**. Yes There is `<EntitySetMapping Name="GamesScores">` section. You just need to add Scalar Property `GameDateCreation` under that which i mentioned above. Please let me know how you go.